# Not able to link CSS and images

Tags: java, css, spring, jsp, spring-security

I am working on a Spring, Hibernate, JSP application. I am trying to display an image from my JSP page. The image not displayed on the browser. I am also not able to link my CSS into JSP page.

My JSP page is:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>
<html>
<head>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body id="page1">
<div class="headerlogo" align="center"><a href=""><img src="images/Logo1.png" alt="" /></a></div>
<div align="center">
    <h1><spring:message code="header.title"/></h1>
    Language :
    <a href="?lang=en_US">English</a>|
    <a href="?lang=sp_SP">Spanish</a>

    <h3>
        <a href="home"><spring:message code="header.gotohome" /> </a>
    </h3>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have set

```
<http pattern="/images/**" security="none" />
<http pattern="/css/**" security="none" />
```

for my images and CSS folders

My Spring Security xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">


    <http pattern="/images/**" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/css/**" security="none" />

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

        <intercept-url pattern="/admin*" access="hasRole('SYS_ADMIN')" />

        <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/role-check"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/login" />

         </http> 

         <authentication-manager> 
        <authentication-provider> 

        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="fmsDataSource"  
        users-by-username-query="select USERNAME,PASSWORD, 'true' as enabled from users where USERNAME=?"
        authorities-by-username-query="select u.USERNAME, ur.AUTHORITY from users u, user_roles ur where u.USER_ID = ur.USER_ID and u.USERNAME =? " />
    </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

Comment: have you confirmed that it works without Spring Security? Please expand your question to include what happens when you attempt to access the css file directly in your browser, and post the debug log output for the request.

Comment: @LukeTaylor - I have not check it without spring security. The browser console have following errors GET http://localhost:8080/demo/css/style.css 404 (Not Found) and GET http://localhost:8080/demo/images/Logo1.png 404 (Not Found)

Comment: If you're getting 404s then it's a basic problem with your app and you should make sure it works without Spring Security first. Look at the Spring Security tutorial sample (or any working other JSP application) to learn how to embed URLs in JSPs.

Comment: @Raman Didn't you satisfy with the answer, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by adding following mapping in `web.xml` file

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.gif</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

and also by adding `<%=request.getContextPath()%>` in image src url.
Like `<img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/logo.png" />`

Comment: Use of scriplets is not recommended if they could be replaced with the tags. Didn't described why this mapping and what mapping is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use JSTL `<link href="<c:url value='/css/style.css'/>"` tag for this the same shoult do for images. `<img src="<c:url value='/images/Logo1.png'/>"`.

You also need to add to the page

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Comment: which jstl jar should be used for this?

Comment: I have used <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
   <version>1.2</version>
  </dependency> in dependency. any thing else to add?

Comment: add   <dependency>
   <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
   <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.2</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>