# Java JSTL assets loading base url instead of correct url

Tags: java, css, servlets, jstl

I'm making this site with Java and I have set my page to load CSS like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/style.css">
```

But when I go to site, it doesnt load that style.

When I look at source code and click path of css file, it loads sites base path even it shows correct path of that css file.

Its same thing with images.

When I try to load bootstrap CSS, it works. Every asset that is included in my project, fails to load.

So basicly if I go to http://url.com:8080/project/css/style.css it redirects to http://url.com:8080/project/

I also loaded css/randomtext.css and same thing happens, no 404 error or anything else on errors log.

I have tried with firefox and IE, both doesnt work.

Any suggestions what might be wrong?

**EDIT:**

Its working after I made these changes:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13233458/1678908

Comment: I managed to get it working with this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13233458/1678908